# Edit divs using jquery depending on which link was clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a nav bar with several different divs that I want to change depending on which link was just clicked

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function (){

      $("#content").load("content/index_content.php");
      $('a').click(function(){
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        $('#nav_' + 'a' + "active");
        return false;
      });
    });
    </script>
```

```
    <span id="nav">
        <a href="content/index_content.php"><div id="nav_home_active></div></a><a href="content/news_content.php"><div id="nav_news"> 
    </div></a>
    <a href="content/staff_content.php"><div id="nav_staff"></div></a>
    <a href="stats.php"><div id="nav_stats"></div></a>
    <a href="content/contact_content.php"><div id="nav_contact"></div> 
    </a>
    </span>
```

The 7th line in the jquery block is all I can come up with and obviously it's not working. How do I concatenate the word "active" onto existing divs to reflect the current page and change the button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do the job:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){

      $("#content").load("content/index_content.php");

      $('a').click(function(){
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));

        let newId = $(this).children("div").attr("id") + "_active";
        $(this).children("div").attr("id", newId);

        return false;
      });

    });
```

However, you may wanna remove all  "_active"  from the links when another link is clicked. This might be a little tricky with ids. I believe you have different css rules for `nav_home` and `nav_home_active`. If that's the case, classes will be more suitable here.
Just create class "active" and assign the css you need. Add or remove this class.

Here is the example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#content").load("content/index_content.php");

      $('a').click(function(e){

        // prevent the page from jumping to another place
        e.preventDefault(); 

        // remove class active from all divs inside <span id="nav">
        $("#nav div").removeClass("active");

        // add class active to link you clicked 
        $(this).children("div").addClass("active"); 

        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')); 


      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` within a jQuery event handler to reference the element that the event handler is responding to.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#content").load("content/index_content.php");

  $('a').click(function(){
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));

    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    return false;
  });
});
```

This will add the class `active` to the link clicked and remove the same class from any siblings. You could then use `a.active` to reference the active link.

**EDIT**

Sorry - realised you were trying to edit the divs, not the links.

You could use `$(this).children('div')` within the handler to access the div within the clicked link.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#content").load("content/index_content.php");

  $('a').click(function(){
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));

    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    $(this).children('div').addClass('active');

    return false;
  });
});
```